# How to return to the place of the last inserted character?

Tags: buffers, cursor

Assume that I open a file and start editing it (at least one character is inserted).
Assume that the cursor is at Place **A** when the last change to the file is done (i.e. the last character is inserted).
Then I take the cursor to another place in the same buffer (say place **B**).
During this, I don't insert anything, but perhaps I execute some commands.

Is it possible to return from the place **B** to the original place **A**?

Comment: This is a duplicate of or related to http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/2807/115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are okay with returning to the last *edit* (as opposed to last *insertion*), you might want to look at the package [`goto-chg`](http://melpa.org/#/goto-chg). You can enable it like this:

```el
(require 'goto-chg)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-.") #'goto-last-change)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-,") #'goto-last-change-reverse)
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's dumb compared to `goto-chg`, and also jumps to any kind of edit, not the last insertion, but I often undo, insert a space, and undo again (that space insert)... which places me back at the point of the last change.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the first undo change the last edit, which may cause come inconveniences in some situations. Maybe I miss something...

Comment: Right, so you make a new edit (insert space), then undo the edit and you're back at the original state.  It's easier to do than to explain :)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Nice hack.